Append incrementing value to some cells with power query
So I'm receiving an Excel file with RefID information provided for TypeA users. This table is named and is on Sheet1



UserType
Login
RefID




TypeA
aaa
9991


TypeA
bbb
9992


TypeB
ccc



TypeA
ddd
9993


TypeB
eee



TypeA
fff
9994


TypeB
ggg




From my end, I need to populate RefID for TypeB users. I know the starting number of this RefID so each next users gets incremented by 1 RefID.
For this purpose, I've created a table using PQ (source - original named table, filtered by "TypeB", created variable that stores initial `RefID, left only Login column and added Index column where my variable is starting index. Table looks like below and is stored on another sheet2 of the same file:



Login
RefID




ccc
1001


eee
1002


ggg
1003



Now I need to add missing RefID into the existing table. If the initial table was created using PQ I would join 2 queries by Login.
What would be the best way to join them, or maybe there is a different way to populate missing RefID?
I don't want to use vlookup as type of the user can be changed from TypeA to TypeB and vice versa, so cell with RefID should be without formulas. And it is preferable not to break the existing table by adding new columns to it.
At the moment looking at this method
Can Power Query output load to an existing Excel table?
But asking just in case there is a working solution.
PS: Would it help if I ask sending party to generate table structure with PQ so when I received half-populated table I can just merge queries?

maybe you can try this
= Table.AddColumn(Source,"Rank",each if [UserType] =  "TypeB" 
then Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(Source,(x)=>x[Login]<[Login] and x[UserType]=[UserType]))+1001 
else [RefID])



Hi Ryan, thanks for the reply. As per original post - it is preferable not to change table structure by adding new columns. Would it help, if I ask sending party to create this table by using PQ so when I receive it I can merge queries?

I don't think you can update the original column. Usually what we do is to create a new column and delete the useless columns. It looks like the column number is the same as original's

But this is achieved by creating a new table in new place that uses original table + merged query ?

you can add a new column in original table. you can also reference a new table and add the new column in the new table

Doesn't that mean that you add data in one place but view it in another?
